# Website with Google Adsense revenue split model

Tags: wordpress, google-ads-api, adsense, ads, affiliate

I'm currently looking to set up a website where users can upload files for download (all legal, no torrents or anything ) and then they share their links to the files and get paid based on the amount views they get.

The website will be filled with news, articles and pages of assets to download all with adsense on but I want to pay the contributors their share of the ad revenue. Is there a way to set it up so I know how much to pay each user based on their views/downloads that month?

I am familiar with Wordpress etc it's just the advertising side of the model i'm a little confused about. Any help would be great. Be similar to this:
http://www.90min.com/affiliates

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the Revenue Sharing API provided by Google Adsense specifically for this purpose: https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/revenuesharing

> As an AdSense Host API partner, you will place AdSense ad code on
>   behalf of your users, and will have the opportunity to keep a
>   percentage of the revenue generated by those ads. Some partners find
>   that it works best to give all of the revenue to their users; each
>   partner has the flexibility to determine the model that works best for
>   their particular site.
>
> You must clearly disclose your revenue share to users on your site
>   prior to AdSense account creation or association. In addition, Google
>   will display your revenue share to your users when they complete their
>   AdSense application or confirm association. This information will also
>   be displayed in the "Account Access" section of each user's AdSense
>   account.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DFP, and include a custom dimension in the targeting that had a user ID, to allow you to pull a report that groups impressions generated by user ID.

https://www.google.com/doubleclick/publishers/small-business/

and

https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_setTargeting